# Low GPU usage while training CNN

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to train a CNN that predicts if an image is an image of a cat or a dog using keras with tensorflow on my GPU, but it's taking a lot of time per epoch.

I followed a tutorial to build this CNN from scratch, so i've installed CUDA 10.0, Visual Studio community 2017, tensorflow on GPU and Keras (all of this using Spyder and Anaconda). But when i started training the CNN i opened the task manager and saw that CUDA is being used by 6-7%. It happens the same when i scan the GPU usage with NVSMI.

My GPU is an NVIDIA RTX 2060.

This is the code i'm running:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))


classifier.add(Flatten())


classifier.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))


classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1./255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            'dataset/training_set',
            target_size=(64, 64),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            'dataset/test_set',
            target_size=(64, 64),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(
            training_set,
            steps_per_epoch=8000,
            epochs=10,
            validation_data=test_set,
            validation_steps=2000)
```

I want to know if there's any chance to set an specific value for the usage of the GPU or at least to make it grow more than 6%.

Comment: 6% means you are not using your GPU

Comment: Or your batch size is too small. Your network is very small and a single batch of your data takes approximately 1.5GB of VRAM, while your card has 6GBs. You should try increasing the batch size to 64. If that doesn't increase GPU utilisation, then @DollarAkshay is probably right.

Comment: It might be that the input pipeline is terribly slow and relies on copying data from CPU memory to GPU. You can use timeline https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d to profile your execution and see what your devices are up to. Also, with an architecture as shallow as yours it might be Ok to have sub 80% GPU-utilization. You can also try to increase number of conv layers - if your utilization goes up in that case, it probably means that your GPU is starving for more data.

Comment: Thanks for answer me. After i made this post, i found out i could use a parameter in the fit method to specify the numbers of threads of my CPU to use. So i set 16 threads and the usage of my GPU grew to 20%. I'll try to use a bigger batch size and i'll notify you, but the GPU is being used.